# Restoring Elasticsearch snapshot excluding ilm indices

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to restore an Elasticsearch snapshot (ES v7.15.2) I am sending a POST request to

```
http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/repository/snapshot_2022-09-08/_restore?wait_for_completion=true
```

with body

```
{
    "indices": "*,-.*"
}
```

which i think should be all indices not starting with `.` but I receive the response

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "snapshot_restore_exception",
        "reason": "[repository:snapshot_2022-09-08/-s19GVP5Syu7FqsuviPclw] cannot restore index [.ds-ilm-history-5-2022.08.12-000002] because an open index with same name already exists in the cluster. Either close or delete the existing index or restore the index under a different name by providing a rename pattern and replacement name"
      }
    ],
    "type": "snapshot_restore_exception",
    "reason": "[repository:snapshot_2022-09-08/-s19GVP5Syu7FqsuviPclw] cannot restore index [.ds-ilm-history-5-2022.08.12-000002] because an open index with same name already exists in the cluster. Either close or delete the existing index or restore the index under a different name by providing a rename pattern and replacement name"
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

So I think the issue is caused by the presence of the ILM index `.ds-ilm-history-5-2022.08.12-000002` but I didn't want to restore that anyway and I though it should be excluded by my index specification in the POST body?

Any ideas where its going wrong?

Comment: what does return `GET _cat/aliases/.ds-ilm-history-5-2022.08.12-000002?v` ?

Comment: `alias index filter routing.index routing.search is_write_index`